# Naming conventions for class method vs instance method

Tags: python

I have two methods, one for the individual Instance, and one for every Instance in that class:

```
class MasterMatches(models.Model):

    @classmethod
    def update_url_if_any_matches_has_one(cls):
        # apply to all instances, call instance method.

    def update_url_if_any_matches_has_one(self):
        # do something
```

Should I name these the same? Or, what is a good naming convention here?

Comment: Don't name them the same as one will overwrite the other.

Comment: And don't name them something that long either.

Comment: I'd just be more descriptive in the classmethod. Something like `update_all_master_matches_instance_urls` to make sure the caller knows that the operation applies to all instances, not just the one being called.

Answer (score 0):

The question of using the same names can be clarified by understanding how decorators work.

```
@dec
def foo(x):
    print(x)
```

translates to

```
def foo(x):
    print(x)

foo = dec(foo)
```

In your example the decorator syntax can be expanded to

```
class MasterMatches(models.Model):

    def update_url_if_any_matches_has_one(cls):
        # apply to all instances, call instance method.

    update_url_if_any_matches_has_one = classmethod(update_url_if_any_matches_has_one)

    def update_url_if_any_matches_has_one(self):
        # do something
```

The former implementation of `update_url_if_any_matches_has_one` will be overwritten by the latter.

Answer (score -1):

Usually use self declaration style. @classmethod use only if method not works with class instance fields.

Function decorated as @classmethod takes the first argument is the class type, while normal method takes instance of object.

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        print(cls)

    def b(self):
        print(self)

a = A()
a.a()
a.b()

# Output:
# <class '__main__.A'>
# <__main__.A object at 0x03FC5DF0>
```

It can be useful if you have a static class fields. The to access therm you don't need explicitly specify the class name. But you don't get access to instance fields. Example:

```
class A:
    field = 1

    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        print(cls.field)

    def b(self):
        self.field = 2
        print(self.field, A.field)

a = A()
a.a()
a.b()

# Outputs:
# 1
# 2 1
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question

Comment: Why not answer? In many cases use self declaration style, if not need have access to class instance fields and need access to class static fields use @classmethod

Comment: The question is about naming conventions.  You explained how they work (and rather shallowly as well, imo)